# Change background of encryption password loadup screen

Tags: desktop-background

I'm looking projects for things involved in Ubuntu. I find the environment of the screen to which you give your full disk encryption passphrase to be bland and would love to change it. Is this an editable feature and what other fun projects do you have in mind that I could try my hand at.